# Writing binary files C++, way to force something to be at byte 18?

Tags: c++, binary

I'm currently trying to write a .bmp file in C++ and for the most part it works, there is however, just one issue. When I start trying to save images with different widths and heights everything goes askew and I'm struggling to solve it, so is there any way to force something to write to a specific byte (adding padding in between it and the last thing written)?

Comment: I don't understand, what's stopping you from writing the padding bytes  before or after you write your data?

Comment: To be honest, neither do I. But when I change it's value, it seems to jump back a byte and there is already padding before it to stop it doing this.

Comment: Sounds like the code you're using to write it out in the first place is simply wrong. You shouldn't need to use fseek() for this.

Comment: I agree but I just can't seem to get it to work, I'll sort the padding out for when the width is a certain value but then when I change the width the padding before it is all wrong for some reason. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several sort of obvious answers, such as keeping your data in memory in a buffer, then putting the desired value in as `bufr[offset]=mydata;`.  I presume you want something a little fancier than that, because you are, for example, doing this in a streaming sort of application where you can't have the whole object in memory at the same time.

In that case, what you're looking for is the magic offered by *fseek(3)* and *ftell(3)* (see [man pages](http://www.unix.com/man-page/OpenSolaris/3c/fseek/)).  Seek positions the file as a specific offset; tell gets the file's current offset.  If it's a constant offset of 18, the you simply finish up with the file, and do

```
fseek(fp, 18L, SEEK_CUR)
```

where `fp` is the file pointer, `SEEK_CUR` is a constant declared in `stdio.h`, and `18` is the number 18.

***Update***

By the way, this is based on the system call *lseek(2)*.  Something that confuses people (read "me", I never remember this until I have been searching) is there is no matching "ltell(2)" system call.  Instead, to get the current file offset, you use

```
off_t offset;
offset = lseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_CUR);
```

because *lseek* returns the offset after its operation.  The example code above gives us the offset after moving 0 bytes from the current offset, which is of course the current offset.

***UPdate***

aha, *C++*.  You said C.  For C++, there are member functions for seek and tell. See the [fstream man page.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/)

Comment: I'm opening the file like this: 
ofstream out("test.bmp",ios::out|ios::binary);
so what do I put ad the file pointer?

Answer (score 1):

Count how many bytes have been written.  Write zeroes until the count hits 18.  Then resume writing your real data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, everything comes to writing predefined structures: ["Bitmap storage"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183391.aspx).

Also there is an example that shows how they should be filled: ["Storing an Image"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145119.aspx).

If you are writing not-just-for-windows code then you can mimic these structs and fallow the guide.